# Can you add to a claims identity in Identity 2.0 without redirecting the user

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

So, if you have a claims authenticated user, and you need to add additional claims that your application needs, can you do that without sending the user back through another request?

What I have is an application that has an existing identity token that is set in a cookie.  I want to push an update that requires us to update that claims identity so it has a new claim.  I don't want to log all the users out.

I'm familiar with using `AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant` to do that in an action method, however, I want to (somehow) detect that it doesn't exist in a global way, and dynamically run that?

Is there a way to use `OnValidateIdentity`?